# Why write a static route, it can communicative to each other in my scene?

Tags: switch, networking

I have a network topology like below:

[image]

In Switch0, Switch1 and Switch2, I added the a SVI. However, it is not possible to reach from one SVI the other ones.

Now, if I write the following static route in Switch2, SW1 and SW3 can communicate, but I don't understand why.

```
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 10.10.10.1
```

---

**EDIT-01**

This is the Switch0 running-config:

```
Switch#show running-config 
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 1341 bytes
!
version 12.2(37)SE1
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname Switch
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
!
interface FastEthernet0/2
!
interface FastEthernet0/3
!
interface FastEthernet0/4
!
interface FastEthernet0/5
!
interface FastEthernet0/6
!
interface FastEthernet0/7
!
interface FastEthernet0/8
!
interface FastEthernet0/9
!
interface FastEthernet0/10
!
interface FastEthernet0/11
!
interface FastEthernet0/12
!
interface FastEthernet0/13
!
interface FastEthernet0/14
!
interface FastEthernet0/15
!
interface FastEthernet0/16
!
interface FastEthernet0/17
!
interface FastEthernet0/18
!
interface FastEthernet0/19
!
interface FastEthernet0/20
!
interface FastEthernet0/21
!
interface FastEthernet0/22
!
interface FastEthernet0/23
!
interface FastEthernet0/24
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface Vlan100
 mac-address 0005.5ed1.7601
 ip address 10.10.10.1 255.255.255.0
!
ip classless
!
ip flow-export version 9
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line aux 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
!
!
end
```

This is the Switch1's running-config:

```
Switch#show running-config 
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 1341 bytes
!
version 12.2(37)SE1
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname Switch
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
!
interface FastEthernet0/2
!
interface FastEthernet0/3
!
interface FastEthernet0/4
!
interface FastEthernet0/5
!
interface FastEthernet0/6
!
interface FastEthernet0/7
!
interface FastEthernet0/8
!
interface FastEthernet0/9
!
interface FastEthernet0/10
!
interface FastEthernet0/11
!
interface FastEthernet0/12
!
interface FastEthernet0/13
!
interface FastEthernet0/14
!
interface FastEthernet0/15
!
interface FastEthernet0/16
!
interface FastEthernet0/17
!
interface FastEthernet0/18
!
interface FastEthernet0/19
!
interface FastEthernet0/20
!
interface FastEthernet0/21
!
interface FastEthernet0/22
!
interface FastEthernet0/23
!
interface FastEthernet0/24
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface Vlan100
 mac-address 00d0.ff83.b201
 ip address 10.10.10.2 255.255.255.0
!
ip classless
!
ip flow-export version 9
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line aux 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
!
!
end
```

This is the Switch2's running-config:

```
Switch#show running-config 
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 1317 bytes
!
version 12.2(37)SE1
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname Switch
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
!
interface FastEthernet0/2
!
interface FastEthernet0/3
!
interface FastEthernet0/4
!
interface FastEthernet0/5
!
interface FastEthernet0/6
!
interface FastEthernet0/7
!
interface FastEthernet0/8
!
interface FastEthernet0/9
!
interface FastEthernet0/10
!
interface FastEthernet0/11
!
interface FastEthernet0/12
!
interface FastEthernet0/13
!
interface FastEthernet0/14
!
interface FastEthernet0/15
!
interface FastEthernet0/16
!
interface FastEthernet0/17
!
interface FastEthernet0/18
!
interface FastEthernet0/19
!
interface FastEthernet0/20
!
interface FastEthernet0/21
!
interface FastEthernet0/22
!
interface FastEthernet0/23
!
interface FastEthernet0/24
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface Vlan100
 mac-address 0002.179a.3701
 ip address 10.10.10.3 255.255.255.0
!
ip classless
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 10.10.10.1 
!
ip flow-export version 9
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line aux 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
!
!
end
```

Comment: Did you configured vlans?

Comment: do you mean if I configured vlan, it can be communicative then?

Comment: yes sure, it will work

Comment: I do not see you create the VLANs with the global `vlan <vlan number>` command. Not doing that can cause problems.

Comment: thank you, this is caused by the not configured vlan.